# Let $S$ be a semigroup. If every finitely generated $T\lt S$ is embeddable in a group then $S$ is embeddable in a group.

Tags: group-theory, logic, model-theory, solution-verification, semigroups

> Let $S$ be a semigroup. If any finitely generated $T\lt S$ is embeddable in some group $G_T$ then also $S$ is embeddable in some group $G$.

I am trying to prove this statement, which is an exercise of a Model Theory course I am attending. Actually is one of the first exercise of this kind I try to solve.

Intuitively it seems to me an application of the compactness theorem. My approach would be something like:

1. Write, in the language of groups, an appropriate theory $\mathbb{T}$ of semigroups embedddable in some group.
2. Show that any finite subtheory of $\mathbb{T}$ has a model if and only if any finetely generated semigroup embeds in some group $G_T$

Anyway I cannot quite formalize it and suspect to be heading in the wrong direction.

Moreover, does this kind of results hold in general for first order algebraic structures?

Comment: It seems false. Assume for instance that $G$ is a free group over countably many elements and $T$ is a free monoid over uncountably many elements...

Comment: Thanks to both, I was definetely recalling the wrong text! I edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** Expand the language of groups by adding a constant for each element of $S$. Let $\Sigma$ be the theory consisting of the group laws plus the diagram of $S$. A model for $\Sigma$ will be a group in which $S$ is embedded. Use the assumption about finitely generated subsemigroups of $S$ to show that every finite subset of $\Sigma$ is satisfiable. It follows by compactness that $\Sigma$ is satisfiable.

Answer (score 1):

We use the product semigroup $S\times G$ with projections $\pi_1\colon S\times G\to S$, $\pi_2\colon S\times G\to G$. An embedding of a subsemigrup of $S$ to $G$ is anything that satisfies the following sentences (details left to the reader):

- is a relation 
  $$\forall x\colon x\in S\times G$$
- is left and right unique
  $$\forall x, \forall y\colon \pi_1(x)=\pi_1(y)\leftrightarrow \pi_2(x)=\pi_2(y)$$
- is closed under  multiplication
  $$\forall x,\forall y,\exists z\colon xy=z.$$

In addition to these, we have (presumably infinitely many, namely one for ech $s\in S$) sentences of the form
$$ \tag{$\star$}\exists x\colon \pi_1(x)=s.$$

We are given that there is a model for every finite subset of $(\star)$ together with the first three ...

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. It seems you're trying to apply compactness to a set of sentences. What is the language, and what are the sentences exactly (I'm particularly worried about the first one). Also, are you starting with a fixed group $G$? Mindlack gave a counterexample in the comments showing this is not possible.